# I am using AutoHotKey, and Send {F12} Won't work, why?

Tags: send, autohotkey

```
    NumPadSub::
Send {F12}
Mousemove 517, 501
Click
return
```

Why wont this work? If I remove Send {F12} the rest works, but with it there, nothing works. I tried SendInput as well.

Comment: Try #installkeybdhook at start of your script and/or sendplay.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is working, actually.  Maybe the program that is active does not respond to the F12 key the way you expect.

I tried this and it works just fine:

```
NumPadSub::
Send {F12}
msgbox dude
return
```

Run your script and push F12 while some other program is active and see if anything happens.

Are you running the ANSI version of Autohotkey?  If so, maybe make sure your file-encoding is set to ANSI in your script file.